# Probability of $7$ out of $7$ children inheriting disease-causing gene

Tags: probability

Hi I am hoping you can help me with this. What are the chances of $7$ out of $7$ children inheriting the gene for Huntington's disease which has a $50$% chance of inheriting the gene for EACH child born to a single parent with the gene? I married into such a family & have wondered this for years!Thank you SO much!!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If the chance for one child is $\frac12$, and each is independent, then the chance for all $7$ children is $\left(\frac12\right)^7=\frac1{128}$, which is less than $1\%$

Answer (score 1):

The probability is the same as that of flipping a fair coin seven times and seeing a head each time. It's
$$
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^7 = \frac{1}{128} .
$$
That's less than one percent.

Comment: Wow-thank you Ethan. What a sad, sad situation but thank you for the answer. Someday, hopefully, there will be a cure for this Huntington's Disease...